# Mirroring Git Repository and Submodules to offline source

Tags: git

So I realize that there are similar questions, but none of them seem to answer the question of how to mirror a repository to an offline location, without having to organize the submodules manually outside the superproject.  Most of the questions are about "online" mirrors, or offline mirrors without submodules.

My first thought was to create a mirror of my superproject, but since the repo is bare, you can't run `git submodule update`.

Now, I know in this situation it's good for your `.gitmodules` to use relative paths instead of absolute ones, and we do that already.

But I still don't quite understand the best way of having a mirror of a superproject and all its submodules.

Our project is made up of one repository with a lot of submodules (~50, but none nested), so manually maintaining them is something I'm trying to avoid.

This has to be possible, but I haven't stumbled on what the best organization is, and how to retrieve it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks yall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this might be to just carry the submodule histories in your main repository.  That way, when you clone your main project, you get all the submodule histories along with it.  The `git submodule` helper command doesn't deal with this automatically, but it's not very hard to wrangle: carry the submodule history you're interested in as a branch named for the submodule.

One-time setup:

```
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.MYSUBMODULE.url ./
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.MYSUBMODULE.path MYSUBMODULE
```

Instead of `git submodule update --init`:

```
git config submodule.MYSUBMODULE.active true
git config submodule.MYSUBMODULE.url ./
git clone -sn . MYSUBMODULE 
git submodule --quiet absorbgitdirs MYSUBMODULE
git -C MYSUBMODULE checkout $(git rev-parse :MYSUBMODULE)
```

So the `-sn` on the clone tells git to not duplicate the object db and not do its usual automatic checkout.  The explicit checkout is of the tracked commit that belongs there, you could even use `git submodule update` instead, it's the same thing.

I keep this stuff as a makefile target, setup depends on utils/.git, utils/.git just checks whether the submodule's needed and sets it up if so:

```
.PHONY: setup
setup:  utils/.git ;

utils/.git:
    @if _=`git rev-parse -q --verify :utils`; then \
        git config submodule.utils.active true \
        && git config submodule.utils.url ./ \
        && git clone -sn . utils \
        && git submodule --quiet absorbgitdirs utils \
        && git -C utils checkout $$(git rev-parse :utils); \
    fi
```

(replace the first whitespace on each line with tabs, markdown doesn't speak tabs)

Answer (score 1):

I think I faced something similar to your issue. My problem was developers on different networks had different paths to submodules. My solution was to use `url.PATH.insteadOf URL` and setting a variable to fill URL. See below. I set GITPUB in my .bashrc to point to where I stored all the public repos.

```
git config --global url.file:///MY/PATH/.insteadOf file:///GITPUB
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.MYSUBMODULE.url=file:///GITPUB/subrepo.git
git submodule sync MYSUBMODULE
git submodule update MYSUBMODULE
```

You'll have to do this for each submodule, but it's easy to do in a script.

We create bundles of the repo and submodules by running the following in repo.git and each submodule.git. `git bundle create myrepo.bundle --all`. You can do increment updates with `since=`. `git bundle create myrepo.bundle --all --since=8/30/19`

On the other side you can pull from the bundle with `git pull myrepo.bundle my_branch` If doing a full export you can mirror the bundle with `git clone --mirror myrepo.bundle`

Comment: How do you get the submodule mirrors downloaded? If the superproject was cloned with --mirror, it's a bare repository, so you can't run git submodule init, right?

Comment: We use `git bundle` to package the repository and each submodule. Then pull updates from the bundle. I'll elaborate above..